# javadoc stackoverflow java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: javadoc, stack-overflow

I am working on the [BYU EDIF Tools Sourceforge Project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/byuediftools/) after downloading the source code and all of it's dependencies I get the following error when trying to generate javadocs for it:

```
C:\Users\akeller9\workspace>javadoc -d byuediftools\doc -sourcepath byuediftools -classpath "byuediftools\JHDL_provisional.jar;byuediftools\JSAP-2.1.jar" -subpackages edu
Loading source files for package edu.byu.ece.edif.arch...
...<more source files loaded>...
Loading source files for package edu.byu.ece.edif.util.parse...
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavaTokenizer.readToken(JavaTokenizer.java:564)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.ensureLookahead(Scanner.java:102)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.token(Scanner.java:95)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.peekToken(JavacParser.java:310)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.peekToken(JavacParser.java:306)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term3(JavacParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term2(JavacParser.java:909)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term1(JavacParser.java:880)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:836)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:816)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseExpression(JavacParser.java:779)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parExpression(JavacParser.java:2260)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2444)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2352)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatements(JavacParser.java:2298)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java:2269)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java:2283)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2441)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2352)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2317)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2445)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2352)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatements(JavacParser.java:2298)
    <<<MANY MORE LINES IN THE STACK TRACE OBVIOUSLY STACK OVERFLOW>>>
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java:2269)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java:2283)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2441)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2352)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2317)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2445)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2352)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatements(JavacParser.java:2298)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java:2269)
javadoc: error - fatal error
1 error
```

When I exclude that last package it appears to be start generating the docs but then the same error occurs.

I am not sure what it is. The idea of dependency cycles in the packages/classes come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

This code base has a deep level of dependency. This causes a stack overflow in `javadoc` because the default stack size is too small to support this level of dependencies.

To work around this a the following flag can be added to the 'javadoc' command:

```
javadoc -J-Xss1m ...
```

This passes the flag `-Xss1m` to the java VM that is running javadoc which increases the stack size to 1 megabyte. See [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) documentation for more information.  After running the command with this option javadoc was able to successfully generate documentation for the [BYUEDIFTools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/byuediftools/)