# StackOverflowError Java 1.8

Tags: java, compiler-errors, jvm, stack-overflow

First time asking a question on here, I've been lurking for a while attempting to search for the answer to this issue but I can't seem to find a proper solution.

```
Information:Using javac 1.8.0_31 to compile java sources
Information:java: The system is out of resources.
Information:java: Consult the following stack trace for details.
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavaTokenizer.readToken(JavaTokenizer.java:560)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.nextToken(Scanner.java:115)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.nextToken(JavacParser.java:301)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.literal(JavacParser.java:759)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.literal(JavacParser.java:659)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term3(JavacParser.java:1157)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term2(JavacParser.java:909)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term1(JavacParser.java:880)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:836)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:816)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseExpression(JavacParser.java:779)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.arguments(JavacParser.java:1779)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classCreatorRest(JavacParser.java:2219)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.creator(JavacParser.java:2103)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term3(JavacParser.java:1166)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.arguments(JavacParser.java:1794)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term3(JavacParser.java:1255)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2392)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatements(JavacParser.java:2298)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java:2269)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java:2283)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2441)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatement(JavacParser.java:2352)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatementAsBlock(JavacParser.java:2317)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2445)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:2449)
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'Server'
Information:5/1/2015 5:45 AM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 952ms
Error:java: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I've never had issues running my program before and I'm not sure what could be the cause of this.

My system has 6 gb of ram available with 1gb allocated to the JVM. When running a previous version, I have no issues.

If anyone could help me troubleshoot what the cause of this might be, I would appreciate it.

**Sorry about the question, I literally copy/pasted the entire source to a different module with the same exact settings and it's working good as new. If anyone has any explanation as to why this is the case, please, let me know.**

Comment: add what you have done

Comment: Give it more memory.

Comment: Duplicate of [javadoc stackoverflow java.lang.StackOverflowError](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27516445/823393)?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - After allocating more ram to the stack size on run I come across the same error.

Comment: @content - Please post some code - take the existing code and remove everything that does not cause the error - post what's left.

Comment: @OldCumudgeon Unfortunately I'm not sure where to start. I've gone through the older save of the project that does not have any errors, removed each piece from the newer project adding the pieces from the older project in place and the newer project still has errors.

As far as posting the code here, I would post relevant code if I knew what portion of it was causing the error. I know I'm not helping you help me very much, but the project is incredibly large and I just don't know where the relevant area of it is.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Thanks for the help. Although I simply copy/pasted all of the directories into a new module with the same VM settings and it's now working good as new.

Comment: Did you upgrade from Java 7 to Java 8? Did you ry to use more memory (-Xmx2048m ? Do you use a 64bit JVM?

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach No changes, same machine, 8 both times. Honestly perplexed as to why the cause may be.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you don't run your program, you compile it. It is the java compiler that dies of stack overflow.

Clearly, your source code is too complicated for the java compiler to deal with. To run the java compiler with more stack space

```
javac -J-Xss4m ....
```

If you don't run `javac` directly, but through some "build tool", this is the time to find out how good it is. A good build tool, while providing reasonable defaults, should let you customize your final compilation command line at will.

Comment: Really not an answer to the question. Thank you for the input anyway.

Comment: to me his answer seems correct, maybe you just don't understand it. if so you should ask for clarification or point out why you think it does not apply to your case.